# Google Firebase notification get request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I read in a previous question that a GET request to the following URL:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=my_device_group
```

would retrieve a `notification_key` for an existing messaging device group. I instead retrieved a new notification key.

I can now send messages to either the existing or the new key, has the group been cloned?

Comment: Well, you can check here in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) how the notification works in your application.
The `notification_key` identifies the device group by mapping a particular group (typically a user) to all of the group's associated registration tokens.

AFAIK if you create a new `notification_key` it will identify a new device group. 

It is also stated here that to create a device group(meaning a new group), the FCM returns a new `notification_key` that represents the device group.